# How do I interpret this density function

Tags: calculus, statistics, stochastic-processes, biology

I'm currently freshing up on math for my computational biology seminar. Now I have a question concerning the following density function that is used to calculate the signaling time in a signaling network of a cell. My book states that this time is based upon the density function;

$$f(t)=\frac{X(t)}{\int_{0}^{\infty}X(s)ds},$$

where $X(t)$ is the count of bound molecules.

How am I to interpret this density function? Do I guess right that $f(t)$ yields the probability of $X(t)$?

Comment: It does not. The integration of $f$, $F(t)=\int_0^tf(s)ds$ yields the probability. It is easy to see that $\lim_{t\to\infty}F(t)=1$. You should have learned PDF and CDF, have you?

Comment: pdf = probability density function; cdf = cumulative distribution function

Comment: Oh ok now I see. My problem was, that I didn't think about integrating again. It sat there right in front of me. Thanks Troy. This makes it all clear.